# How do I install the Microsoft BotFramework-Emulator?

Tags: botframework

I am running Windows 10 and want to install the BotFramework-Emulator.

The link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-emulator?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#download-the-bot-framework-emulator) says

> Download packages for Mac, Windows, and Linux are available via the GitHub releases page.

Well I go to that link [the GitHub releases page](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases) and I do not see anything about how to download and install a windows package.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Github release page, you have the choice between several file types for direct install:

- **AppImage**: **Ubuntu** package (2 versions available, depending on your machine architecture: i386.AppImage and ...x86_64.AppImage)
- **mac.zip**: for **Mac OS**
- **exe**: for **Windows**
- **deb**: **Debian** package (2 versions available, depending on your machine architecture: amd64.deb and i386.deb)

Comment: Bear in mind, the 4.0.15 version is a preview version, and as such, can be occasionally quirky as it is actively being updated. 3.5.36 is the last stable release.

Comment: @JJ_Wailes is right.  I tried using the 4.0 preview version of the emulator and I couldn't click the buttons that reside in the PromptDialog.Choice(). I looked in the settings of the emulator and saw nothing, so I had to hunt for version 3 of the emulator.

Comment: I don't have this problem on my v4 emulator with PromptDialog.Choice, but yes, there can be some problems in preview versions

Comment: How to bring the emulator up in OS X?

Comment: @srinannapa what do you mean by bringing up the emulator?

Answer (score 1):

botframework-emulator-setup-4.0.15-alpha.exe   seems to be it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the releases here: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases

For the stable version, you can download from [stable release](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases/download/v3.5.36/botframework-emulator-Setup-3.5.36.exe)

And if you want to get a touch of new UI, you can go with the [preview release](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases/download/v4.0.15-alpha/botframework-emulator-setup-4.0.15-alpha.exe) which is v4.0.15 alpha as of today